# Story or theory about us people ultimately becoming god

Tags: story-identification

I read a story on the internet about a theory which said, that some of us can become god ultimately.

People get born, die and get reincarnated. The crux of this story was, that whenever a human dies, he takes some of his knowledge/experience into his next life until he gathered enough to create/rule his own universe and become god.

Does anybody know the original story?

Comment: Is this a fictitious book about science fiction or fantasy? Or a supposedly non-fiction book detailing the fate of men in some religious context?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're describing Buddhism

Comment: No, it wasn't a book. It was a short story I stumbled over while randomly browsing the web. It was about 3 or 4 years ago.

Comment: http://www.galactanet.com/oneoff/theegg_mod.html?

Comment: @Valorum That's it. Can you tell me how did you find it?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1wrSsIVqHpM